# Removing for loop using sapply

Tags: r

As a learning exercise in removing for loops using sapply in my code below I'm attempting to return the minimum of a vector using sapply :

```
f3 <- function(nv) {
    min(nv)
}

myv = c(1:10)
y <- sapply(myv, f3)
y
```

As expected instead of applying the min function to entire fector to return 1, the min is calculated for each element in the vector returning `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`.

How can I use sapply to process the entire vector, therefore returning 1 ?

Comment: If you change the `vector` to a `list` then it returns just `1`. Does it need to be in vector format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply `min` to the whole vector like so

```
myv <- 1:10
min(myv)
#> [1] 1
```

`min` will return the minimum of any number of arguments you give it. If you've got a more complicated data structure than a vector such as a dataframe and you want the minimum for each column than you might want to use `sapply` although there are other alternatives. Here's an example of where using `sapply` might make sense:

```
mydf <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20, z = 21:30)
min(mydf)
#> [1] 1
sapply(mydf, min)
#>  x  y  z 
#>  1 11 21
```